# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, formatting, raspberry-pi

On a Raspberry Pi, I've set it up so that it's monitoring ASCII serial input from the user, which it then parses and populates a matrix with the parsed data. But when I try to do something with the data:

```
for i in range(1,7):
    if matrixA[i][1]>0:
        print "sending DO_Fire (pin %d) HIGH for %dms, with a power level of %d"%(DO_Fire,int(matrixA[i][1]),int(matrixA[i][2]))
        os.system("pigs m %d w wvclr wvag 16 0 %d 0 16 10000 wvcre")%(DO_Fire,int(matrixA[i][1]))
        os.system("pigs m %d w wvag 0 16 %d 16 0 10000 wvcre wvtx 0")%(LED_Fire,int(matrixA[i][2]))
```

It prints the message just fine, but it has issues with the command line operation, citing the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

At first when I did this, I was using `$s`, so then I figured I just needed to cast the data as an `int`, but that hasn't made any difference.

What is it that I'm missing? Any advice or helpful input would be greatly appreciated.

Full traceback below, as requested:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "rs232.py", line 974, in <module>
line =  readLine(ser)
File "rs232.py", line 131, in readLine
goA()
File "rs232.py", line 184, in goA
preheats() #detect all stored preheats and fire them
File "rs232.py", line 147, in preheats
os.system("pigs m %d w wvclr wvag 16 0 %d 0 16 10000 wvcre")%(DO_Fire,int(matrixA[i][1]))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: which line raises the error?  post the full traceback.

Comment: You are formatting a tuple as an integer with `%d`.

Comment: You have the brackets wrong - you are trying to format the **return value** from `os.system`, which is an integer, not the argument to it.

Comment: `os.system("pigs m %d w wvclr wvag 16 0 %d 0 16 10000 wvcre")%(DO_Fire,int(matrixA[i][1]))` and the line after that will attempt to use '%' on the result of `os.system()`. For this and the line after, you need the bracket to be outside the `%` expression.

Comment: Thanks for your input, folks! Martijn got me straightened out with the proper parentheses placement.

Comment: In future, do include the *full traceback* of the error you are getting. You may want to add it in now anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `os.system()` call returns an integer (the process exit code). You want to apply the `%` operator *to the string argument*, not the return value of the function.

You are doing this:

```
os.system(string) % tuple
```

instead of

```
os.system(string % tuple)
```

Move those parentheses:

```
os.system("pigs m %d w wvclr wvag 16 0 %d 0 16 10000 wvcre" % (DO_Fire, int(matrixA[i][1])))
os.system("pigs m %d w wvag 0 16 %d 16 0 10000 wvcre wvtx 0" % (LED_Fire, int(matrixA[i][2])))
```